# How to keep data constant after merging from 2 or more csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a big data CSV file. I managed to merge them into one CSV file. Now when I read the file its is not consistent inflow. For example :

```
file1 CSV: id date 
           21 2001
           21 2002
           21 2003
           22 2001
           22 2001
           22 2002
file2 CSV: 21 2006
           21 2005
           21 2007
           22 2006
           22 2006
```

and so on.
Now when I merge all files in one CSV i want output like

```
   id date 
   21 2001
   21 2002
   21 2003
   21 2006
   21 2005
   21 2007
   22 2001
   22 2001
   22 2002
   22 2006
   22 2006
```

Code:

```
All <- lapply(filenames_list,function(filename){
  print(paste("Merging",filename,sep = " "))
  read.csv(filename)
})

df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind.data.frame, All))
write.csv(df,merge_file_name)
```

this is the code I did to merge all files in one CSV. Kindly help me to keep them in an organized pattern.

```
dput(head(newdata1,10))
structure(list(X = 1:10, gvkey = c(7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 
7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 7041L), datadate = c(20000103L, 
20000104L, 20000105L, 20000106L, 20000111L, 20000112L, 20000113L, 
20000114L, 20000117L, 20000118L), cshoc = c(4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 
4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 
4.2e+07), cshtrd = c(112000, 637000, 241000, 251000, 224000, 
194000, 175000, 217000, 307000, 326000), prccd = c(3.86, 4.28, 
4, 4.04, 4, 3.96, 3.92, 3.96, 4.06, 4.14), prchd = c(3.86, 4.6, 
4.22, 4.26, 4.26, 4.04, 4.1, 4.02, 4.2, 4.3), prcld = c(3.3, 
3.86, 3.9, 3.96, 4, 3.9, 3.92, 3.88, 4, 4.02), prcstd = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), qunit = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), cheqv = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), cheqvgross = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    div = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divd = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divdgross = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), divdnet = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), divdtm = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    ""), divgross = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), divnet = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divrc = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divrcgross = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), divrcnet = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), divsp = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), divspgross = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), divspnet = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divsptm = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), anncdate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), cheqvpaydate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), divdpaydate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), divrcpaydate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), divsppaydate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), paydate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), recorddate = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), split = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), splitf = c("", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", ""), trfd = c(1.05474854, 1.05474854, 
    1.05474854, 1.05474854, 1.05474854, 1.05474854, 1.05474854, 
    1.05474854, 1.05474854, 1.05474854), monthend = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fyrc = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ggroup = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), gind = c(201070L, 
    201070L, 201070L, 201070L, 201070L, 201070L, 201070L, 201070L, 
    201070L, 201070L), gsector = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), gsubind = c(20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L, 
    20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L, 
    20107010L), naics = c(999990L, 999990L, 999990L, 999990L, 
    999990L, 999990L, 999990L, 999990L, 999990L, 999990L), sic = c(9995L, 
    9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 9995L
    ), spcindcd = c(400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 
    400L, 400L, 400L), spcseccd = c(970L, 970L, 970L, 970L, 970L, 
    970L, 970L, 970L, 970L, 970L), ipodate = c(19920103L, 19920103L, 
    19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L, 
    19920103L, 19920103L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Output after merging 3-4 file of csv]

Comment: What is your expected output for given data? Which columns do you want to keep? Which ones do you want to remove?

Comment: I want the output should be in an organized pattern such as id all should be in stacked after merging all files.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what do you mean by organised pattern. Maybe remove the columns which are not important and then share the `dput` along with expected output so that it is clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please refer to the image. This the output after merging all CSV files in one CSV. Now when you see 214 its id is 7041 and the date is 2004-12-31, but there are more values of id 7041 which are not stacked under this. So for example, 320 have id 7041 and the date is 2005-01-01. I want to see all id values continuous, means after 214 rest other values should come under 215, 216,217...and so on.

Comment: I guess what you need is `arrange` from `dplyr` : `df1 <- df %>% arrange(id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your ideal outcome correctly, you want to order the data.frame df by the column ID and then save this as a csv file. If so, in your code you can add a line using order() and sort by id in ascending order and then save that data frame. By putting order inside the square brackets [] it retains the rest of your data. By putting order before the comma , inside the brackets, the data becomes ordered by the row values.

Instead of:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind.data.frame, All))
write.csv(df,merge_file_name)
```

Add the line with order:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind.data.frame, All))
new_df <- df[order(df$id),] 
write.csv(new_df,merge_file_name)
```

For a full example:

```
# Create two data frames
df1 <- data.frame(gvkey = c(1:6),
                  dat = runif(6))

df2 <- data.frame(gvkey = c(1:6),
                  dat = runif(6))

# bind them by the rows 
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# order by gvkey
new_df <- df[order(df$gvkey),]
```

Comment: ``newdata2<-newdata1[order(gvkey),]

write.csv(newdata2,merge_file_updated)``
gives error
``Error in order(gvkey) : object 'gvkey' not found``

in my case id name is gvkey

Comment: Let say i have 4 CSV file, all file have same gvkey(id) with a different date. when I merge all files they show me all values as in csv file existing. I want gvkey should be in order like the first gvkey(id1) of all files then 2nd gvkey(id 2) and so on.

Comment: Ah sorry! Just need to specify where gvkey is. Hopefully this should work `newdata2<-newdata1[order(newdata1$gvkey),]` . If so, I'll update the answer